# How to code a collision and reaction between two objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a pong style game with 1 player. I have set it up so a ball will change direction when hitting the border of the screen but, I can't make a code that does the same if the ball was to hit another object in the screen

I've made this code using Khanacademy so the size is 400px by 400px

Here is my current code

```
var ballx = random(50,350);
var bally = (50);
var ballxmovement = 2.5;
var ballymovement = 2.5;
var padwidth=80;
var padheight=10;
draw = function(){ 
ballx += ballxmovement;
bally += ballymovement;
noStroke();
background(0, 0, 0);
fill(255, 255, 255);
rectMode(CENTER);
rect(mouseX,350,padwidth, padheight);
fill(255, 255, 255);
ellipse(ballx,bally,20,20);
if (bally > 400) {
        ballymovement = -2.5;
    }
if (bally < 0) {
        ballymovement = 2.5;
    }
if (ballx > 400) {
        ballxmovement = -2.5;
    }
if (ballx < 0) {
        ballxmovement = 2.5;
    }    
};
```

What I'm trying to have happen is when the ball hits the rectangle it will react in the same way as it would when hitting the border.

As per request, I've presented the unsuccessful code that I made to create the reaction.
I changed the rectangles y position to a variable named recty.

```
while(ballx===mouseX){
    if(bally===recty){
        ballxmovement = -2.5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"What I'm trying to have happen..."*: I actually don't see any attempt to do that. As it stands, your question is too broad. Instead, show the code you have been trying with to detect a hit on the rectangle, and point at where you are getting a wrong result or error.

Comment: @trinot I should've added the code when creating the post. Sorry about that, I am relatively new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First you could use switch case or if else for code refactoring,also if you know the position of the object(x,y co-ordinates) you could use them in the condition to achieve the bounce back effect while it reaches the desired position

```
//if(ballx >= 400 ) subtract the values
//else if (ball7 >= 400) subtract the valuew
//else(ballx=== x co-ordinate and bally === y co-ordinnate) subtract the value
```

Try the above sudo code this could solve your usecase

Comment: srry meant try something similar to the sudo code is that what your say...?

Comment: But this question is not about sudo, but about JavaScript.

Comment: If you see thesudo  code, i think i have provided with idea for the solution, its just some basic syntax that has to be written, i dont see the need ,if thats whats required i woud be happy to do it. also i just gave the  person a idea, i think that more important than  the code

Comment: Maybe you meant [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)? It certainly is not related to sudo.